# foreach statement giving an error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, foreach, rss

I am using the following code:

```
private string covertRss(string url)
    {
        var s = RssReader.Read(url);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (RssNews rs in s)   //ERROR LINE
        {
            sb.AppendLine(rs.Title);
            sb.AppendLine(rs.PublicationDate);
            sb.AppendLine(rs.Description);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I am getting an error:

> Error  1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(System.Collections.Generic.List(Cricket.MainPage.RssNews))' because 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(System.Collections.Generic.List(Cricket.MainPage.RssNews))' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

The RssNews class is:

```
public class RssNews
    {
        public string Title;
        public string PublicationDate;
        public string Description;

    }
```

What code should i add so the error is removed and the purpose of the code is not compramised?
Thanks in advance!

Code for RssReader.Read()

```
public class RssReader
    {
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<RssNews>> Read(string url)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            string result = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url); 

            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(result);

            return (from descendant in document.Descendants("item")
                    select new RssNews()
                    {
                        Description = descendant.Element("description").Value,
                        Title = descendant.Element("title").Value,
                        PublicationDate = descendant.Element("pubDate").Value
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `RssReader.Read` is returning?

Comment: although programme is not running.It is meant to read from the feed,the entire xml of the feed.

Comment: Post your code for `RssReader.Read()` method.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `await`:

```
foreach (RssNews rs in await s)
```

or:

```
var s = await RssReader.Read(url);
```

Do **not** use `Result`; if you do, you can easily [cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog.

As a side note, I recommend that you read and follow the guidelines in the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). If you do, you'll find that your method `Read` should be named `ReadAsync`, which gives your calling code a strong hint that it needs to use `await`:

```
var s = await RssReader.ReadAsync(url);
```

Comment: I did that Mr.Cleary , After that , we are making the method async, the method returns string type, which is not accepted,Hence giving an error! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AllanElder Which, given that the edit shows an `async` method, is clearly the case.

Comment: @YashVj You'll need to change the return type to `Task<string>`.

Comment: Then the following code would return me an error:              public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            string readableRss;
            readableRss = covertRss("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");
            textbox.Text = readableRss;
        } The error is :Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'

Comment: @YashVj: Then you need to [asynchronously initialize](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html), as I describe in my blog. Note that your UI will need an additional state for "loading" - most people just show a spinner or a loading message while the asynchronous initialization is going.

Comment: @StephenCleary Or just use `Task<string> s = await RssReader.ReadAsync(url);` after changing it to use `Task<string>` as the return type.  Exactly why I think using `var` is a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing an `await` statement.

It appears `s` is of type `Task<List<RssNews>>`.

You either need this

```
var s = await RssReader.Read(url);
```

or

```
var s = RssReader.Read(url).Result;//this is blocking call
```

Of course when you use `await` you need to mark the method `async` as well.

Here is how you go

```
private async Task<string> covertRss(string url)
{
    var s = await RssReader.Read(url);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (RssNews rs in s)   //ERROR LINE
    {
        sb.AppendLine(rs.Title);
        sb.AppendLine(rs.PublicationDate);
        sb.AppendLine(rs.Description);
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter let me know why? If you can't give a reason don't vote it down

Comment: +1, this looks good, I am not sure why it has been downvoted.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but when you do `.Result`, you don't need to `await` it.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i have already made the method async. It can be seen in the code. It is still giving an error!

Comment: @TimS. Thanks, That was copy and pasted. Fixed.

Comment: @YashVj the problem isn't with `Read`, it's `covertRss`.

Comment: Why serial downvote? Kindly provide reason for downvote, so that I can improve my answer.

Comment: Sorry, when I downvoted it, the answer just said "I think you're missing an await statement"; seems like you've edited it since to incorporate my answer, too.

Comment: @AllanElder I was revising my answer.. Just drop a comment when you downvote. If the answer is completely stupid you don't need to comment. but "I think you're missing an await statement" is valid pointer isn't it?

Comment: I did both the steps! if we use async, its giving an error that string method can't be async.if we use the other method , the app doesn't go further the splash screen.Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: @YashVj Check my updated answer, You'll have to mark the return type as `Task<string>`. async methods can either return void or `Task`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the task itself in the loop. You need to use the Result property

```
foreach (RssNews rs in s.Result)
```

since from the exception it appears to be a List that will be returned.